# get number into string with javascript/regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
MyString = "big BANANA: 5, pineapple(7), small Apples_juice (1,5%)_, oranges* juice 20 %, , other fruit : no number "
```

I'd like to get the number of each element in my `MyString`.

The separator for decimal can be a comma or a dot.

The code I've tried:

```
function getValue(string, word) {
  var index = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()),
      part = string.slice(index + word.length, string.indexOf(',', index));
  return index === -1 ? 'no ' + word + ' found!'             // or throw an exception
                      : part.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: correct the code format

Comment: 1,5 or 1.5? which is correct?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oO3bNy/1 maybe it could work (works for your test cases, but should be modified, probably, for numbers with more digits, etc,etc)

Comment: 1,5 or 1.5 are corrects

Comment: Sorry I have changed my question because I was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, looking at your example string you want to get numbers from parts that can be splitted by a comma and a whitespace `,`.

If that is the case, then this might be an option:

- Create an array using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and loop the items
- Check if the word you are looking for in present in the item using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- Use a pattern like [`\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/ZglgjH/1) for the match
- If you have a match, return it.

For example:

```js
var MyString = "big BANANA: 5, pineapple(7), small Apples_juice (1,5%)_, oranges* juice 20 %, , other fruit : no number ";
function getValue(string, word) {
    var items = string.toLowerCase().split(', ');
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    var pattern = /\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/g;
    var result = 'no ' + word + ' found!';
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
            var match = item.match(pattern);
            if (match && typeof match[0] !== 'undefined') {
                result = match[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getValue(MyString, "big BANANA"));
console.log(getValue(MyString, "pineapple"));
console.log(getValue(MyString, "small Apples_juice"));
console.log(getValue(MyString, "oranges* juice"));
console.log(getValue(MyString, "other fruit"));
console.log(getValue(MyString, "ApPle"));
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work if for example console.log(getValue(MyString, "ApPle")); – observatoire 1 min ago   edit

Comment: @observatoire I have updated my answer adding `.toLowerCase()` for the check.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rewriting your code to put your values in an object:

```
var myObj = {
   bigBanana: 5,
   pineapple: 7,
   smallApplesJuice: 1.5,
   ...
   }
```

You can then iterate through myObj values with a simple for...in loop.

If this is not feasible, you'll have to create different code using RegEx for every substring you want to get our of your big string. For example, try this to get the value of Apples_juice:

```
//create a regular expression that matches everything after "Apples_juice":
var re = new RegExp(/((?<=Apples_juice).*$)/);
//extract three characters that follow "Apples_juice (":
var extracted_value = MyString.match(re)[0].substring(2,5);
```

Note that extracted_value is a string, which you will then have to convert to a number. Hope this helps.